# Как сгенерировать WSDL файл на Java

Tags: java, wsdl, soapui, wsimport

Имеется soap веб сервис и его WSDL описание: `https://ws**.demo.**.com/WsBatch/service.svc?wsdl`.

```
wsimport -keep -verbose https://ws**.demo.**.com/WsBatch/service.svc?wsdl
```

получаю такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом на основании сгенерированного wsdl, хотел создать Web Service Client на Java и из БД отправить данные. Помогите как сделается?

Comment: Что значит `... не могу сгенерировать.`? Напишите в вопросе что именно происходит.

Comment: @defaultlocale откорректировал вопрос. Может я совсем не правильно делаю ?

Comment: URL на картинке не везде замазали. WSImport говорит об ошибке 401, через браузер адрес доступен?

Comment: @defaultlocale Да, доступен.

Comment: 401 — ошибка авторизации. Попробуйте проверить настройки прокси сервера (не стоит ли адрес в исключениях прокси для браузера, в системных настройках)

Comment: @defaultlocale Все включен, ни где не стоит запрет именно на этот адрес. Еще есть другие способы сгенерировать wsdl файл ?

Answer (score 0):

Для авторизации, необходимо создать файл `auth` в `%userprofile%\.metro` следующего содержания

```
http://login:@host/service.svc?wsdl
```

или

```
http://login:pass@host/service.svc?wsdl
```

если заданы и логин, и пароль.
Либо указать ключ `-Xauthfile` для `wsimport` примерно так:

```
wsimport -Xauthfile path_to_auth_folder\auth -keep http://host/service.svc?wsdl
```

Comment: .metro как попасть ? Или мне необходимо создать файл с именем metro и там же хранить файл auth.txt ?

Comment: Нет же! .metro это папка в профиле пользователя, а auth текстовый файл (без раширения)

Comment: Это тоже не помогает, может я совсем не правильно делаю. Exp: Создал файл auth содержанием логина и пароль. Сохранил в пользовательском папке (%Пользователь%\Администратора). 
-Далее: wsimport -Xauthfile path_to_auth_folder\auth -keep https://ws*****/service.svc?wsdl 

Код ошибка 401

Comment: @Ulukmyrza в файле пароль и логин и всё? а url?

Comment: url - тоже имеется. Мы можем через почту или скайп переписываться ?

Comment: @Ulukmyrza можем, но тогда ответ не узнает широкая аудитория

Comment: Мы потом разместили бы результат. Просто тут никак не могу скриншот послать и т.д.

Comment: @Ulukmyrza укажите как связаться